# Getting current user ID in page tab

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to find the ID of the user visiting my page tab (without having to make him authentify before using the page)

I've tried several methods:

```
$requete_fb = $facebook->api('/me');

$me = $facebook->api('me', array('fields' => 'username'));

$request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();

$uid = $facebook->getUser();
```

But all of them did not work (getUser returns me 0, the others PhP errors.)

So how can I do that? I'm not trying to break the TOS, I'm trying to fetch basic information (the locale).

Any other way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to get a user_id without the user's permission:

> The user_id and oauth_token will only be passed if the
>   user has authorized your app.

However the `locale` is available in the user object.  Please see [Signed Request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/) for more information.

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to replace the SignedRequest because it started returning Null on every request this morning. Still does it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11653362/getsignedrequest-always-comes-back-null

Comment: That’s not the way to go. Figure out what your problem with getting the signed_request is, instead of trying to think of workarounds that might break at any time or might not even be possible.